# New high quality tire doesn't sit evenly on the rim

Tags: tire, innertube

It's my first tire change experience and I got so far using youtube videos but now I'm stuck.
Got these Schwalbe 365 tires yesterday for my folding bike.
It is an all season model which feels a bit harder than the tire that was on the bike from the factory but both are 40-406 20x1.5".
The bead doesn't sit properly on the rim. This is the case from both sides as seen in the images. There's a small misalignment between where the problem manifests itself on each side of the rim.
The tube is also brand new (Continental). The temprature in the bicycle room where I tried is around 16-22 deg.

Hadn't used soapy water when installing the tire and can't measure tire pressure (it's recommended 3-6 bar).

What do you recommend to solve the issue?

[image]

Update: bought a pump with gauge, rotated the tire and used a bit of liquid soap to end up with this result:

[image]

One thing that I discovered today is that the tire is literally tighter at the point where there's a problem which makes me think the tire might have some issues due to how it was stored I  the shop. But that would be too sad because despite the issues I really like these tires.

Comment: Note that the reflective bands on Schwalbe tyres don't always run parallel to the tire bead, so you should check tyre seating by other features on the tyre, not by these bends.

Comment: In these tires they are perfectly in place (as well as my new 26" bike).

Comment: One thing to check is that you have the right tubes.  An oversized tube may fold and create a lump, while an undersized tube may not inflate evenly.  (Yeah, not too likely for a 20-inch tire, but definitely a risk with 24/26 inch tires and some of the older road tires.)

Comment: This is the tube: https://m.bikester.se/continental-compact-20-cykelslang-svart-260192.html which if I understand correctly fit any tire 32-406 > 47-451 mine is 40-406

Comment: Given the efforts you've made to get the tyre to seat properly with no success I would remove and examine the tyre, particularly around the problem area. It is quite possible that this is due to a manufacturing default, and if this is the case, you should return the tyre and have it replaced with a new one.

Comment: The tire wasn't faulty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tire sidewall is just hung up on the rim a little. It’s a common problem.

Deflate the tire until you can deform it a little with your hands, rotate the wheel so the problematic section is at the top. Grab the tire from the side and lever it back and forth. You should be able to pop it out so the bead sits on the rim properly.

BTW, a pressure gauge is a good investment so you know you are inflating your tire to the proper pressure.

Here's a link to Park Tool's video on tire installation, at the point it addresses the bead being too high or low.

.

Comment: Some soapy water on the rim-sidewall interface can also help. It also helps to do it in a warm environment -- ie., leave the bike outside in the sun for a while if it's sunny (be sure to lock it up!) -- or gentle application of a hairdryer.

Comment: For more leverage I have clamped the tire in a vise before torquing on the wheel to get a suborn tire to seat.

Comment: I did everything you said (except the sun part because I'm in northern Europe) and updated the question with a slight improvement. I guess I need to lubricate it even more (today's soapy water was too little) but I don't dare to pump it more than 100 psi and my pump gauge doesn't even have more than 100! 

Comment: @AlexStack If the pumping to max pressure does not work, you need to *deflate* it so the tire is almost loose on the rim, You should be able to push the sidewall in off the rim with your thumbs, then essentially push and pull it manually until it seats properly.

Comment: I deflated it (even removed and installed it again). An interesting discovery was that when it's half deflated it's possible to shape the tire a bit but that still doesn't solve the problem entirely.

Comment: Fixed the problem after reading about it on Schalbe's website and watching some more videos. The trick is to inflate it a bit and massage the tire to the correct shape (took me 10m for the first tire abd 5m for the second) and inflate more. Deflate and repeat if results are not satisfactory. If your could add this tip to your answer I can accept it as the best answer because I got most of the tips from yours.

Comment: @AlexStack what you did is actually what I was suggesting

Comment: @AlexStack I can tweak language though

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes I've found that pumping up the tyre to the rated pressure (or *a little* over), deflating most of the way, and pumping up again does the trick.  You can chuck some water on the bead while its deflated (I use plain rather than soapy water for that; it's not as effective but doesn't leave a slippery residue)

You can also try riding a few hundred metres gently with the tyre fairly soft then pumping up hard.

A pump with a pressure gauge is really useful for stubborn tyres, I run mainly Schwalbe, and some of theirs can be tricky, though I've had worse.

Comment: Conti even recommends 150% of the rated pressure to seat some of their stiffer touring tyres. That may not always be advisable though!

Comment: @gschenk funnily enough the "I've had worse" referred to contis, though I hadn't seen that advice. I'd push my marathons that hard if necessary but haven't needed to, and wouldn't risk it with cheap tyres

Comment: The idea with running the bike half deflated is a good one. Will give it a try (updated the question with today's efforts)

Comment: I've been driven nearly demented by the same problem on new Schwalbe Marathons. The idea picked up here of test riding on low pressure finally solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Pump up the tire more until it seats itself properly on the rim. 
Deflate to desired pressure afterwards.

Comment: This did the trick for me on Schwalbe G-One.

Answer (score 3):

Great advice from everyone; my issue was tightening the valve stem nut before inflation, which seemed to pull the tyre down around the valve not allowing the tyre bead to pop. So if anyone that is running tubes still has issues, maybe should try that, loosen the valve stem nut before inflating.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I've had this exact same problem seating some schwalbe g-ones.  They were tubeless tyres and I'd put tubes in them.

It didn't matter what i did, and I basically followed all of the above suggestions, they'd never seat properly.

The moment I removed the tubes and ran them tubeless they seated perfectly, clicked into the rims @ about 80 psi and I've never had any subsequent issues with them. The issue appeared at a random point just as yours have.

I have a sneaking suspicion that it was that the tubes put pressure on the wrong part of the tyre as its inflated.  So my suggestion is that you try with a different diameter tube. I'm not sure if it should be larger or smaller, but give it a go with one you have handy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried that repeatedly, as I'm sure they poster has.  It clearly hasn't fixed  his, or my problem. BTW, The lines always run perfectly around the tyres, yes these are certainly not seating correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When I fitted a new Schwalbe Marathon Plus, it kept bulging near the valve when I tried to inflate it. The solution was to replace the inner tube with a smaller one. I also discovered that the trick to getting the tyre on is to secure it with cords or cable ties as you work around, to stop one side slipping off.
Edit: Thanks to the guys who suggested this in their responses.

Answer (score 2):

Dont rule out the RIM Tape. I was led to this post because I was having problems mounting some 30mm and 32mm tyres on a front rim. I ruined the first tyre being a little too aggressive. When I had the same problem with the second tyre I started to wonder if there was a problem with the rim itself.

Did the soap, did the higher than recommended pressure...still no luck. Looking closer at the wheel after taking the tyre off I wondered if the fabric rim tape that was used could have been my problem. Replaced the fabric rim take with some of that yellow plastic tape rim tape and on my next attempt the tyre seated perfectly.

The rim in question was shallow and I think there was just enough friction with teh fabric tape to prevent the bead moving to the edge.

Shame about the first ruined tyre but I am happy that I got this seated on the second tyre.

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents here because this needed surprisingly more work than expected. Deflate, squeeze tire to center, add soapy water all around, inflate until it pops. I had issues with a Schwalbe Rocket Ron and it popped nicely into place 90% but last 10% needed a deflate, more soap, gradually inflate + massage. I thought it's gonna blow but it did not and last bit popped into place finally. I did not expect this level of massaging when I got a MTB...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tire is properly seated and the tube is not pinched anywhere. Then pump up to maximum allowed pressure (or even slightly higher). *If* the tube is pinched anywhere it will rupture with a very loud bang. If you are unsure, better wear some hearing protection or do it outside and keep as much distance to your head as possible.

Deflate to desired pressure afterwards.

Sometimes it’s actually the reflective stripe which is misaligned.

Comment: It would be much better to make sure first that the inner tube is not pinched between rim and tyre by Argenti Apparatus' method.

Comment: It's not pinched. I even redid the whole process carefully again just to make sure of this.