# Tyre not aligned with rim

Tags: tire, repair, rims

So I just replaced my bike rim since the spokes & hub were way too old. I go on and and install same tyre but with new inner tube - so essentially only things that changed are rim and inner tube.

As I fit the tyre on the rim there's a clear misalignment  - the white line on the tyre is wobbling as I drive.

[image: Tyre with misalignment highlighted]

Notice how the distance between the white line on the tyre and the rim changes. The picture is with the air pumped in.

I've tried everything & seems same issue as asked in this other question (I mainly tried removing air, adjusting it with tools & hands, and pumping it back on): [New high quality tire doesn't sit evenly on the rim](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/new-high-quality-tire-doesnt-sit-evenly-on-the-rim)

Also please note that before the rim + inner-tube change the tyre was aligned with rim.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** since question was closed and in the mean time I figured how to fix this: plain brutal force. With inner-tube full of air I used a "tire seater" tool to just force it into place. Mild movement won't work here, just jerk the hell out of it until it's in place. Worked for me :)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because, as you point out, it appears to be the same issue as the other question you linked to. If it is somehow a different issue, please edit your question to show the difference. Once you do that, it will automatically be flagged for reopening. If it is the same issue but the answers on the other question don't solve your problem, you can add a [bounty](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to draw more attention to that question.

Answer (score 1):

It can be that the rim tape isn't seated right, and in places the tyre isn't where it should be. This lost mm or two can result in what you are seeing.

Basically at the point you are showing, the bead of the tyre isn't sitting in the groove of the rim. You need to get it to be in the right place. There is a tool for grabbing the tyre to manipulate it into place, although I have not had luck with it myself.

You can remove the tyre completely, and wet the bead all the way around, which can help it slide into place.

When the tyre is deflated, make sure the valve isn't pinched under the tyre - it should be ablo to push it up easily.

You can (over) inflate the tyre to say 100psi - this might pop it into place. Once it's done, drop the pressure back down again.

Keep trying, it should be possible to get it right